# Deploying MEAN stack application to Heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy an application I am building with the MEAN stack to Heroku and am having some trouble. I think the issue is with the structure of my application. I have all my server code in a folder called server, which has its own `package.json` and `src` folder that contains the actual server code.

Right now I am simply trying to get Heroku to deploy the client side of the application. I am only getting an error... I know that the database and server are not running but I cannot even get past the initial displaying of the app. I have one web dyno set up to **run** `ng serve` `(npm start)` on the app.

If someone would be willing to look at the structure of my application and sees why I am unable to deploy to Heroku without really digging into the code, that would be much appreciated.

[Here is the code](https://github.com/EmersonMax139/AngularSPA/tree/deploy)

Please note that it is on the `deploy` branch, and this is on purpose. I do not want to push anything to the master until I am sure it is working.

Comment: What does "having some trouble" mean? What is the error that you're getting? It's not there for fun; it contains important information. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The Angular web server targets localhost:4200 by default. That can be changed with a couple command-line options. `--port` accepts a port and `--host` accepts a host IP address.

So you could modify the ng serve script as follows: `ng serve --host [host-ip] --port [port-number] --disableHostCheck`. That last flag (`--disableHostCheck`) tells the dev server to bypass host checking when normally `ng serve` fails on anything except localhost. Terrible idea if meant for anything except private development/testing.

Another issue: Heroku runs off web dynos and from what I understand about them, they use a random port and IP each time. While the random port is stored under the variable $PORT, the IP does not seem to have a similar variable. Web dynos keep that information to themselves.

Heroku does offer this command: `heroku local web`. It runs your application on localhost:5000. That means `ng serve --port 5000` works perfectly with this command. This should tell you how your front-end will run on Heroku. Your angular dev server will function as expected too.

For actual deployment to Heroku, use that express server of yours. Run `ng build` from your file system and it will spit out an `index.html` in the `dist` folder. This file holds your entire front-end application. You can then upload that file into your browser from the server.

For express that usually breaks down into:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('path/to/index.html');
});
```

Hopefully this helps! Let me know if I missed the mark anywhere.

Comment: First of all, thank you! I wrote out that question in desperation last night and looking at it now I see that I didn't really describe my issue at all but basically just posted a link to my code. You were right in that the issue was that I was still trying to use ng serve in production, which makes no sense. I have no experience deploying an app so I didn't understand the difference, but I see now that it was just a way to test while developing.I ran ng build and took the resulting files and put them in a repo with my server files, and am going to use this for production. Thank you again!